# How many times does a function produce output?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I have a function f(n) for which I wish to get a count of the number of times f(n) yields an integer for a given arbitrary number k. Specifically, if n has factors of 3,5, or 7, f(n) will generate a number which is the square of that factor or combination of factors that divide n, otherwise, f(n) is blank. For example, f(1)=""; f(2)=""; f(3)=9; f(4)=""; f(5)=25;... f(7)=49;... f(15)=225; ..f(21)=441; ... f(105)=11025.  I want to find how many non-blanks are generated if k=105.

I have tried the sum INT(105/3)=35 + INT(105)/5)=21 + INT(105/7)=15 and I get 71 but the proper number is 57 obtained by actual count. In the cases of 3*5=15, 3*7=21, and 5*7=35 as divisors of 105, we have counted twice so we should subtract one fo each. In the case of 3*5*7=105 as a divisor, we have generated only one entry (11025) but we have counted three times. The problem is that, to get the count of 57 I desire, I need to account for 14 occurrences of counting the prime factors more than once. I keep coming up with 16 or 12. Can anyone suggest the proper way to count non-blanks?

Comment: You are trying to reinvent _inclusion exclusion_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle - that will tell you how to deal with $105 = 3 \times 5 \times 7$.

Comment: Less generally, it looks like what you're looking for is the value of the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) at $105$ -- defined as the count of numbers between $0$ and $105$ that are relatively prime to $105$. Since $\varphi(3\cdot 5\cdot 7)=(3-1)(5-1)(7-1)=48$, that's how many inputs you _won't_ get any output for.

Comment: Try to put your Question in laTex. to avoid Downvotes

Comment: No, I'm actually trying to get a count of primitive triplets generated by another function. By generating multiples only (GCD>1) I can subtract these from the total (105 here) and get the desired count (48 primitives in 105 triplets generated).

Comment: The totient function is interesting and the answer I really seek is 48 for 105 inputs but I would want 49 for 106, 50 for 107, 50 for 108, 51 for 109 etc. I'm weak in this area. Is there a more general function of algorithm for finding n-nonblanks out of k-entries? Or for finding the number of blanks that remain?

Comment: The article about the inclusion/exclusion principle gave me what I needed to see that 71 -3-5-7  +1 = 57. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker MSE suggests I consider a bounty on this question but you provided the answer I needed in your comment. If you would post your comment as an answer, I would check it correct and (I think) you would get $25$ points.

Comment: @poetasis Thanks, but I'm not happy taking that much credit for a comment, no matter how useful. I think you should answer your own question (now that you know how) and accept your answer, so the question comes off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got just what I needed from Ethan Bolker who provided a link to wiki's [inclusion exclusion principal page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). I am only answering to take it off the open question queue. Thanks again Ethan.